# RSS time not being read correctly?

Tags: php, date, time, rss

The answer to this question is probably quite simple - but I'm stumped.

I built a slideshow that pulls from this RSS feed (http://uvmbored.com/event/?feed=events) and  displays a box for each event, headlined by the Day of the week, Month, and day. Followed by the time of the event and title of the event.

However the times were always showing up 4 hours **BEFORE** their time in the RSS feed was set as (so a 10pm event was showing up as 6pm). Originally I thought the issue was with the reader I was using to convert the info to HTML - but in checking out the markup in Firefox I've noticed the same problem. When the browser reads the markup it displays the time incorrectly.  However when you 'view source' and look at the raw markup the times are correct (except in 24-hr format).

So for example:

In the [RSS Markup](http://uvmbored.com/event/?feed=events) for Lake Champlain Shipwreck Tours the  is set as: Sat, 25 Aug 2012 11:00:00 +0000; but Firefox (and my slideshow before I took the time out of it) is displaying the time as 7:00AM as opposed to the 11:00AM it *should* be.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Weird!  Not the case for me (http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/7219/screenshot20120823at253.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "+0000" in "Sat, 25 Aug 2012 11:00:00 +0000"  means the time is represented in UTC (basically, London time in winter). If your PC (and the server running your PHP) is in a different timezone, that would explain the difference in display.

Comment: Makes sense!  Any suggestions on the most practical way to fix the problem?  I guess since even a browser's reader interprets the +0000 - the solution would be to alter the pubdate on the uvmbored.com side of things, as opposed to altering my rss2html code.  Thanks for the help!